# Web2py will refuse to connect under https

Tags: networking, python, port, http

I'm working with a Digital Ocean droplet (VM) running a Debian OS. I wanted to run Web2py, so I opened port 443 for both in and out on the firewall. I ran the start up command to run on my public IP on port 443, and it worked. It connected in HTTP. However when I went to HTTPS it gave me a time out or a protocol error.

I cannot access the admin panel with HTTP, so i cant make apps, making it impossible to do anything with it!

What's going on?

EDIT: because some people are confused, I am runing web2py on a public ip, on port 443, HTTP works, HTTPS doesn't

Comment: You may want to clarify what exactly you are attempting to do by editing your question. The default application admin interface is under e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/shell/index/welcome` according to the web2py documents. If you changed the port to 443, then you (obviously) can't use HTTP.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Heres the wired thing, HTTP works, HTTPS doesn't, I even changed the port to 442, it works the same (worked for HTTP, not HTTPS)